# State List drawable does not show up in all screens

Tags: android

I have a drawable named btndonate.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:constantSize="true" android:dither="true"
android:variablePadding="true"
>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/donate_hover"
    android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_donate"
    android:state_window_focused="true"  />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/donate_hover"> </item>
<item android:state_focused="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_donate"></item>

</selector>
```

I am using it in activity's xml like

```
        <Button android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btndonate" android:id="@+id/btn_home_donate"></Button>
```

i am using the same button with different id's in my other activities xmls.. but it shows up in some and hidden in others i dont know y the same button does not show up n all my activities though the drawable is same for all of them .. ??

any one plz help ??

Answer (score 0):

That's odd... Are you sure, you didn't make any mistakes?
Do you use the same xml file for your script?

Try using this:

```
Button anyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.anyButton);
anyButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Hope this helps. Don't forget to mark correct when it works. ;)